# On Kindle devices can you open an ebook as an email attachment?

Tags: kindle-fire, kindle-app, sideloading

I know that you can email a Kindle ebook to the device itself using Kindle Personal Documents Service. I've been told that you cannot download a file directly using the Kindle Fire web browser.

If I opened up a `.mobi` file as an email  document attachment on a Kindle device,  would I be presented with the option to open it in Kindle? Or is the only way to do this through Kindle Personal Documents Service or Calibre?

(I'm writing a how-to about how to sideload on various devices and don't have access to a Kindle Fire at the moment).

Comment: You use 'kindle device' & 'Kindle Fire' as synonyms in this question.  Can you clarify if you are looking for an answer for just the 'Kindle Fire' or if you are looking for an answer for all Amazon devices?

Comment: Well, it's obvious that e-ink devices don't have email apps. I'm talking only about Kindle android devices which have the ability to receive emails. I went ahead and answered the question below.

Comment: Kindle paperwhite has internet (email) and can download file's in `AZW` `mobi` and more formats, but not `PDF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely download a .mobi file from the web browser on a Kindle Fire ---> retrieve it from the downloads section of your web browser---> and load it into your books library without the aid of a USB cable (sideload) I did it this morning.

Just make sure once you download it in the web browser go to the top left menu options and then a drop down bar will appear and click on 'downloads'.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Ipad/iBooks let you open `.epub` files from email attachments. So does Nook/Android. (You can also download them from a URL).

As far as I can tell though from the Amazon.com website, there is no way to open/add a `.mobi` file from email or a browser.

Comment: Wait, so you aren't talking about the generic e-ink Kindle? They *can* actually download and read `.mobi` books so I would suppose the Fire *definitely* could.

Comment: He's talking about side loading and loading material that is not from the sanctioned store but from another online source